# Ready-made solution for pedestrian osm routing

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to add pedestrian osm routing to my page. I have a root v-server. Which open source solution can I use on my server - I do not want to depend on other servers' reachability - that has most of the work already done?

This is my server:

```
  description: Computer
  width: 64 bits
  capabilities: vsyscall64 vsyscall32
*-core
     description: Motherboard
     physical id: 0     
   *-harddisk
        description: Harddisk
        free space: 16GiB
   *-memory
        description: System memory
        physical id: 0
        size: 2GiB
   *-cpu
        product: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6128
        vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
        physical id: 1
        bus info: cpu@0
        version: 15.9.1
        size: 2GHz
        width: 64 bits
        capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nonstop_tsc extd_apicid amd_dcm pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save pausefilter
      *-cache:0
           description: L1 cache
           physical id: 0
           size: 128KiB
      *-cache:1
           description: L2 cache
           physical id: 1
           size: 512KiB
```

Comment: Duplicated question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/28124/ready-made-solution-for-pedestrian-osm-routing

Comment: The other question may have other answers which might be more helpful. Additionally cross-posting is not very nice.

Comment: @scai I am not very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess chosing the right software depends heavily on your requirements:

- served area
- machine performance (CPU, RAM, shared services)
- internet traffic
- usecase (deploy to 3rd parties/professional users/regular endusers/...)

I agree that **OSRM** is a very good (here: fast and reliable) solution. Disadvantage is mainly the huge precalculated database that needs space and time for computation/updating.

**[YOURS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS)** is also wellknown and has some different pos. features (diff. routing profiles, height calculation, ...). Disadvantage are the runtime resources and lower speed.

**[GraphHopper](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GraphHopper)** is new (at least to me), but should be very fast to it's approach and so is similar to OSRM?

AFAIK none of this solution is "ready-made" and needs some work to get it running in your desired configuration. Thats because they are just services for a very limited semiprof. usergroup ;)
Alternatives might be to invoke real applications as Navit, Gosmore, ...

(Found via http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers)

Comment: As you wrote "machine performance (CPU, RAM, shared services)" I updated my question. I tried OSRM but each time I encountered this problem: https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/issues/799

Comment: 2 GB memory is very little for such heavy computations.

Comment: I agree, that this machine isn't a good choice, if you want to offer a highly reliabale service to your endusers. So either you are able to upgrade your machine, or you need to tweak your requirements (smaller area, simpler routing, less requests, lower update frequency, ...)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to use [OSRM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSRM) with OSM data and the [foot profile](https://github.com/DennisOSRM/Project-OSRM/tree/master/profiles).